# How to handle modified .xcodeproj files in a git submodule

Tags: ios, git, git-submodules

This is more of a process question, but here goes:

I have an iOS project with custom build settings. My repository is stored in Git. I'd like to use submodules to include a couple of open source libraries (AlamoFire and SwiftyJson, as an example).

However, I've found that because of the custom build settings, I have to modify the build settings in the .xcodeproj of the submodules. This causes problems because I can't figure out how to sync this with other developers on my team.

The one solution I have thought of is to make a second .xcodeproj in my main repo that includes all of the files from the submodule, but that's not ideal.

Is there a way to share my submodule .xcodeproj modifications with other developers on my team?